# I want to display something in a dialog in MFC Dialog-Based but it doesnt display anything in my main dialog !

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

this is my code to display something in dialog, I put these in OnPaint() but when I build it there is nothing in my main dialog.
I really appreciate it If anyone can tell me the code mistake.

```
CmyDlg::OnPaint()
{

  CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

  // TODO: Add your message handler code here
  dc.MoveTo ( 10, 10 ) ;
  dc.LineTo ( 200, 10 ) ;

  CPen mypen ( PS_SOLID, 3, RGB( 0, 0, 255)) ;
  CPen *oldpen = dc.SelectObject ( &mypen ) ;
  dc.Rectangle ( 10, 20, 200, 100 ) ;
  dc.SelectObject ( oldpen ) ;

  mypen.DeleteObject( ) ;
  mypen.CreatePen ( PS_DOT, 1, RGB ( 0, 0, 255));
  oldpen = dc.SelectObject ( &mypen ) ;
  CBrush mybrush ( RGB( 255,0,0)) ;
  CBrush *oldbrush = dc.SelectObject ( &mybrush ) ;
  dc.RoundRect ( 10, 120, 200, 220, 20, 20 ) ;
  dc.SelectObject ( oldbrush ) ;
  dc.SelectObject ( oldpen ) ;

  mypen.DeleteObject( ) ;
  mypen.CreatePen ( PS_DASH, 1, RGB(0,0,255)) ;
  oldpen = dc.SelectObject ( &mypen ) ;
  mybrush.DeleteObject( ) ;
  mybrush.CreateHatchBrush ( HS_CROSS, RGB ( 255, 0, 255 ) ) ;
  oldbrush = dc.SelectObject ( &mybrush ) ;
  dc.Ellipse ( 10, 240, 200, 340 ) ;
  dc.SelectObject ( oldbrush ) ;
  dc.SelectObject ( oldpen ) ;

  mypen.DeleteObject( ) ;
  mypen.CreatePen ( PS_DOT, 1, RGB (0, 0, 255)) ;
  oldpen = dc.SelectObject ( &mypen ) ;
  CBitmap mybitmap ;
  mybitmap.LoadBitmap ( IDB_BITMAP1 ) ;
  mybrush.DeleteObject( ) ;
  mybrush.CreatePatternBrush ( &mybitmap ) ;
  oldbrush = dc.SelectObject ( &mybrush ) ;
  dc.Pie ( 250, 10, 350, 110, 350, 110, 350, 10 ) ;

  oldpen = ( CPen* ) dc.SelectStockObject ( WHITE_PEN ) ;
  oldbrush = ( CBrush* ) dc.SelectStockObject ( NULL_BRUSH ) ;

  POINT pt[5] = { 250, 150, 250, 300, 300, 350, 400, 300, 320, 190 } ;  
  dc.Polygon ( pt, 5 ) ;
  dc.SelectObject ( oldpen ) ;
  dc.SelectObject ( oldbrush ) ;

  CRect r ;
  GetClientRect ( &r ) ;
  dc.TextOut ( 100, 200, "Raindrops on roses & whiskers on kittens", strlen ( "Raindrop on roses & whiskers on kittens" ) ) ;
  dc.DrawText ( "Of Words'n Figures", -1, &r, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER | DT_CENTER ) ;
```

Comment: As I recall `OnPaint` is by default not called for an MFC dialog. You can add the requisite machinery (as I recall I did), or use a control to display things.

Comment: @alf: I can't recall having to do anything special in MFC dialogs in order to handle WM_PAINT.

Comment: @Jörgen: huh, maybe it was something else then. Perhaps the OP just needs to InvalidateRect or something, e.g. in OnDialogInit.

Comment: I think he just forgot to add ON_WM_PAINT() to his message map...

Comment: How you have displayed the dialog box? DoModal, ShowDialog - show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

Add ON_WM_PAINT() to your message map.

Comment: thanks Jorgen !
I also have this in my .cpp file :

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Ctest4Dlg, CDialogEx)
 ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
 ON_WM_PAINT()
 ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
 ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &Ctest4Dlg::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

but still my dialog didnt display anything to me !

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in OnPaint, does it break execution if you debug the app?

Comment: I guess this question is already closed, but the MESSAGE_MAP you wrote above is for the class `Ctest4Dlg`, the class in your question is `CmyDlg`. Add ON_WM_PAINT() to the MESSAGE_MAP of the class that has the method.